# Spring Data Neo4j - How to register a node entity and a repository at runtime

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I create a node entity and a repository with using javassist at runtime. And, I want to register them to spring data context. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can have an instance of Neo4jMappingContext injected and then call

```
ctx.getPersistentEntity(My.class)
```

This registers the class with the mapping context.

For the repository it has to go to the spring rewiring, not sure about runtime registration there.

Comment: Although I can not test the any crud operation, I believe that node is registered as you mentioned way. So, thank you for your advice :)
For repository, I inspected the logs and I found that

  RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser - Registering repository: processInputConfigRepository - Interface: com.ns.deneme.neo4j.repository.ProcessInputConfigRepository - Factory: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean

I assume that I need to register the repository bean to GraphRepositoryFactoryBean